# Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void getSObject

Tags: apex

Trying to save a child object from a parent object. Both are custom objects. The parent object name is Claims_Client_Risk_Assessment__c.

The child API name: CCRA_LOB_NonStdAuto__c contains a MSTR detail field with an API Name: Claims_Client_Risk_Assessment__c with a Child Relationship Name : PROD_CCRA_Non_Std_Autos .

Getting the following error:

*ClaimsClientRiskAssessmentController Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void getSObject(List) from the type Claims_Client_Risk_Assessment__c*

---

**Visualforce Component & Controller**

```
    <apex:component controller="PROD_CCRA_LOB_NonStdAutoController" >
      <apex:attribute name="NonStdAuto" type="CCRA_LOB_NonStdAuto__c" assignTo="{!NonStdAutoObj}" description="CCRA non standard auto LOB" required="true"/>    
      <apex:attribute name="record" type="Claims_Client_Risk_Assessment__c" description="CCRA Parent Object" required="true"/> 

      <apex:pageMessages id="globalMessages" rendered="false"/>
      <apex:messages title="data incorrectly entered." style="background-color:yellow; color: blue" /> 

    <apex:form id="form1">
     <apex:pageBlock id="block1" dir="" >
     <apex:actionRegion immediate="true" >

    <apex:outputPanel Style="width:100%;" layout="block">
    <apex:pageBlockSection id="Summary" title="" columns="2" showHeader="false" >

     <apex:pageBlockSectionItem dataStyleClass="col"  >
      <apex:outputLabel value="Does Client perform adequate investigations to confirm coverage for driver and vehicle at issue?"  StyleClass="col1"   />
        <!-- <apex:actionRegion > -->                         
           <apex:inputField value="{!NonStdAuto.Client_perform_adequate_investigation__c}" styleClass="col2" > 
           <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="NSA1a,NSA1b,NSA1c" / >                    
           </apex:inputField>
        <!-- </apex:actionRegion> -->
     </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

         <apex:pageBlockSectionItem dataStyleClass="col"  >                         
         <apex:outputLabel value=""   /> 
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem> 

        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem dataStyleClass="col"  >
         <apex:outputPanel id="NSA1a">
          <apex:outputLabel value="Please comment as needed to describe the diligence of their coverage investigation:"  StyleClass="col4" rendered="{!IF(CONTAINS(NonStdAuto.Client_perform_adequate_investigation__c,'Yes'),true,false)}"   /> 
          </apex:outputPanel>                    
        <apex:outputPanel id="NSA1b">
         <apex:inputField value="{!NonStdAuto.Comment_diligence_coverage_investigation__c}" styleClass="inputFieldStyle1" rendered="{!IF(CONTAINS(NonStdAuto.Client_perform_adequate_investigation__c,'Yes'),true,false)}"  />                 
      </apex:outputPanel>                                
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem dataStyleClass="col"  >
       <apex:outputPanel id="NSA1c">                                               
     <apex:outputLabel value=""  rendered="{!IF(CONTAINS(NonStdAuto.Client_perform_adequate_investigation__c,'Yes'),true,false)}"  /> 
     </apex:outputPanel>                                    
   </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
</apex:pageBlockSection>

  <apex:outputPanel id="OutputHTMLTabPanel">
        <html>
        <body>
        <table class="htmlDataTable" > 
        <td>
           <apex:inputField value="{!NonStdAuto.Closing_Ratio_BI_PY__c}" styleClass="col2" >
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="OutputHTMLTabPanel"  / >                    
            </apex:inputField>
        </td>
        </table> 
        </body>
        </html>
        </apex:outputPanel>

        </apex:outputPanel>
       </apex:actionRegion>
       </apex:pageBlock>
     </apex:form>
    </apex:component>
```

**Component Controller**

```
public class PROD_CCRA_LOB_NonStdAutoController {
    public CCRA_LOB_NonStdAuto__c NonStdAutoObj {get; set;}
    public PROD_CCRA_LOB_NonStdAutoController() {
    }    
}
```

**Parent Visualforce Page**

```
<apex:page id="page" standardStylesheets="true" standardController="Claims_Client_Risk_Assessment__c" readOnly="false" extensions="ClaimsClientRiskAssessmentController" showHeader="true"  >
<apex:form id="form1">
<apex:pageMessages id="globalMessages" rendered="false"/>
<apex:messages title="data incorrectly entered." style="background-color:yellow; color: blue" /> 

<apex:commandButton value="Save Parent and Child" immediate="true" action="{!SaveMe}" styleClass="button" style="background:lightblue;color:blue;border-radius:15px;" /> 
<apex:actionRegion immediate="true" >
    <apex:tabPanel switchType="client" selectedTab="name2" id="theLOBTabPanel" headerClass="tabPanel" tabClass="activeTab" inactiveTabClass="inactiveTab" >
        <apex:tab label="Non Standard Auto" name="tabLOB1" id="tabLOB1" > 
            <apex:outputPanel >
            <c:PROD_CCRA_LOB_NonStdAuto NonStdAuto="{!LOB_NonStdAuto}" record="{!Claims_Client_Risk_Assessment__c}" />
            </apex:outputPanel> 
        </apex:tab>
    </apex:tabPanel>
</apex:actionRegion>
```

**Parent Controller**

```
public class ClaimsClientRiskAssessmentController {

   public Claims_Client_Risk_Assessment__c CCRA { get; set; }
   public CCRA_LOB_NonStdAuto__c LOB_NonStdAuto { get; set; }  
   public Claims_Client_Risk_Assessment__c thisObject { get; set; }  
   public Claims_Client_Risk_Assessment__c record { get; set; }

   private final ApexPages.StandardController stdController;

    public ClaimsClientRiskAssessmentController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        try {                  
         this.stdController = controller;
         this.CCRA = (Claims_Client_Risk_Assessment__c) controller.getRecord();
         this.LOB_NonStdAuto = new CCRA_LOB_NonStdAuto__c();  //instatiate the LOB to receive parent ID
         record=this.CCRA;

         //build up LOB fields to pass to component.
         this.LOB_NonStdAuto = queryLOB_NonStdAuto(this.CCRA.Id);            
            }   
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ApexPages.addMessages(ex);
        }
    }  

//Public Methods

    Public Void SaveMe() {
        try {     
           Database.upsert( CCRA );
           LOB_NonStdAuto.Claims_Client_Risk_Assessment__c = CCRA.id;
           LOB_NonStdAuto.Name = CCRA.Name;
           Database.upsert (LOB_NonStdAuto );
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ApexPages.addMessages(ex);
        }
    }


// populate Viusalforce component fields.

    Private CCRA_LOB_NonStdAuto__c queryLOB_NonStdAuto(Id CCRA_ID) {    
    LOB_NonStdAuto = [
        SELECT 
            Id
            ,Claims_Client_Risk_Assessment__c
            ,Client_perform_adequate_investigation__c
        FROM 
            CCRA_LOB_NonStdAuto__c 
        WHERE 
            IsDeleted = false 
            AND 
            Claims_Client_Risk_Assessment__c = :CCRA_ID 
        ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC NULLS FIRST LIMIT 1
   ];        
        return LOB_NonStdAuto;    
    }

} //End Class
```

Comment: In the future, please "edit" your question instead of posting additional updates as a comment or, in this case, an answer. I've taken care of it for you this time.

Comment: Sure. Thanks. I was trying to maintain consistency with the previous comments as the original question changed fundamentally. @sfdcfox

Comment: Updated the component page because I am seeing the field 'Client_perform_adequate_investigation__c' on the component page saves but the field ' Comment_diligence_coverage_investigation__c ' does not save. It gets cleared out when calling SaveMe() from the parent button. Is this because of the action support on the field that reRenders .vs the rendered field ? @sfdcfox

Comment: The `immediate="true"` part might be an issue. Try removing it.

Comment: Took immediate="true" off the component <apex:actionRegion > markup but these other fields are still not saving.  @sfdcfox

Comment: Added actionSupport event="onchange" to the input field ' Comment_diligence_coverage_investigation__c '  . That allows me to save it from the parent call. Is there an easier way to enable this for all fields on the component's object ? @sfdcfox

Comment: Added reRender="NSA1b" to the field ' Comment_diligence_coverage_investigation__c ' which allows the parent to update the component page and save it. Now the question is why do I need to add the actionSupport tag to every field. is there another attribute I can pass to the component to avoid this ? @sfdcfox

Comment: Figured out the issue and updated the markup. The Visulaforce component contained pairs of <apex:actionregion></apex:actionregion> tags wrapping actionSupport on fields.  These embedded pairs (commented out) caused the wrapping of <apex:actionregion> around the entire pageBlock to not update all the fields inside of it. Removed the embedded <apex:actionregion></apex:actionregion> pairs and now the component fields are not cleared and are also saved by the Parent. Thanks @sfdcfox for sticking this out ! I've also confirmed this with SFDC support.